# Unable to return boolean value properly from a function

Tags: python, loops, return, break

I am a very new python learner and trying to make a tic tac toe game in python. With my current lines of code I am unable to return boolean values properly.

```
board = ['-', '-', '-',
         '-', '-', '-',
         '-', '-', '-']


def display_board():
    print(f"{board[0]} | {board[1]} | {board[2]}")
    print(f"{board[3]} | {board[4]} | {board[5]}")
    print(f"{board[6]} | {board[7]} | {board[8]}")


def win_checker():
    if board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == "X":
        print("Player X Won!")
        return False
    else:
        return True


game_running = win_checker()


def play_game():
    while game_running:
        player_move = int(input("Select from 1 - 9: "))
        board[player_move - 1] = "X"
        display_board()
        win_checker()
        player_move = int(input("Select from 1 - 9: "))
        board[player_move - 1] = "0"
        display_board()
        win_checker()


display_board()
play_game()
```

This only has a single winning position but I will add that later. The problem is that even after the board list has index 0 to index 2 as "X" the loop doesn't break/terminate but it still prints "Player X Won".

Comment: There are some other problems with your code that you will soon discover - but the immediate problem is because you never update the value of `game_running` inside your loop. You should replace those calls to `win_checker()` with `game_running = win_checker()` in order to make use of the return value. (EDIT: you'll also need `global game_running` inside your function for that to work.)

Comment: Make a test case where player O has one of those squares.

Comment: As noted, a number of probelms here. Another one of which is the "won" test: `if board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == "X"`will check whether `board[1]` is set to anything at all, same with `board[2]`, then it will see if `board[3] == "X"`, so basically, since positions 1 and 2 are always set (even  if to "-"), this will be true as soon as position 3 is set to "X".

Comment: `if board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == "X"` is not the right way to check if all of those values are equal to X.  Try `if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == "X"`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, really appreciate you putting your time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `win_checker` function is working properly. It is returning the boolean values. But, you are not saving the returned boolean values to any variable.

Inside the while loop you have to save the returned value to a variable.
Change your `play_game` function with this,

```
def play_game():
while game_running:
    player_move = int(input("Select from 1 - 9: "))
    board[player_move - 1] = "X"
    display_board()
    game_running = win_checker() # updated
    player_move = int(input("Select from 1 - 9: "))
    board[player_move - 1] = "0"
    display_board() 
    game_running = win_checker()# updated
```